# What are "get well" efforts?

Tags: meaning, terminology

What is the meaning of the phrase "get well" efforts?

For example:

"Get Well" efforts for newly deployed systems were becoming a standard practice and were consuming funds intended for more advanced systems. [(Source)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-1Ks-u48W6IC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22Get%20Well%20efforts%20for%20newly%20deployed%22&source=bl&ots=oGup8oPERN&sig=SHs45qatz0F53ub2JGgf28NCQ9k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGkuO2qJjNAhVnJMAKHXIWBkgQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Get%20Well%20efforts%20for%20newly%20deployed%22&f=false)

Comment: Immediately before the cited text it says *major weapons systems were entered into the fleet and encountered severe readiness and supportability problems*. Obviously the "get well" efforts are attempts to resolve those teething troubles, which divert funds away from "more advanced" systems (presumably, newer systems which have not *yet* been entered into the fleet).

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers.  I've just been looking at the context, and I read it as "efforts to repair the newly deployed systems" - in the literal sense of "get well" when a person is unwell.

Comment: "get well efforts" could have been written as "recuperative efforts".

Comment: How was the context and Google not good enough here?

Comment: This question is not off-topic. If you Google "get-well efforts", this thread would come first, followed by unhelpful resources that define "get well soon" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get-well plan** is a common term, at least in the U.S., as you will find if you google it. At the same time, I couldn't readily find a definition in the usual sources or evidence that **get-well plan** is an accepted idiom.

Nevertheless, I found the following on a U.S. Department of Defense [website](https://dap.dau.mil/aap/pages/qdetails.aspx?cgiSubjectAreaID=9&cgiQuestionID=106578) [emphasis added]:

> As the name implies, a *get well plan* is simply an outline to the
>   solution of a problem, which is situational and program specific.
>
> An actual *get well plan* may entail acquiring additional funding,
>   making a schedule change, working with the sponsor to defer a
>   capability need, obtaining a waiver for a contractual specification,
>   etc., or any combination of these or any number of other techniques,
>   to solve a problem. Usually, the hardest part of any *get well plan* is
>   getting started, which requires careful problem definition, that is,
>   precisely defining the problem you are trying to solve before
>   formulating a *get well plan* to solve it.

One could develop a **get-well plan** in any domain, e.g., IT, acquisitions, safety, where significant problems or weaknesses exist, typically systemic, that need to be corrected.

"Get well efforts", as referenced by the OP, pertain to the efforts associated with implementing a **get-well plan**.

Answer (score 0):

From context, not-quite-ready systems were being deployed, and so resources were going into fixing things that were wrong with them, and putting logistical systems into place to support them.

> ...major weapon systems were entered into the fleet and encountered severe readiness and supportability problems... In many cases, the fleet did not receive required logistics support resources... **"Get well" efforts** for newly deployed systems were becoming a standard practice and were consuming funds intended for more advanced systems.

The quotes around *"Get well" efforts* indicates that this is well-understood jargon in this professional context.

Comment: I think those are scare quotes, suggesting that it's not well-known jargon, but a new metaphor being created.